# Remove Material-Ui TextField border

Tags: material-ui

I'm trying to remove the border around a outlined textfield

```
            <TextField
                variant="outlined"
                label=""
                multiline rows={55}
                placeholder="# Hello World"
                style={{ width: '90%' }}
            />
```

but no solutions that i have found worked. I've tried to tinker with all i can find but none remove the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like a `TextField` without the outline border, the best thing to do would be to use the Standard variant of the `TextField` Component.

By default the Standard variant will have an underline beneath the text, but this can be removed by adding `InputProps` prop and passing in `disableUnderline: true`:

```
  <TextField
    InputProps={{disableUnderline: true}}
    variant="standard"
    label=""
    multiline
    rows={55}
    placeholder="# Hello World"
    style={{ width: '90%' }}
  />
```

The result will look exactly the same as if you had an outlined `TextField` without the outline.

Note that it's not recommended you do this, though, for usability reasons; it'll make the text field less distinguishable and less of a clear touch target for users on mobile. Make sure you have some other kind of indication that it's a text field.
https://medium.com/google-design/the-evolution-of-material-designs-text-fields-603688b3fe03